# why two columns are pressed together?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web

[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CTll.png)

Why projects and blog are pressed to each other?
No matter of font-size

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-6"><img src="../img/logo.png" alt=""></div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1  top-puller bolder">Home</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1  top-puller bolder">About</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1  top-puller bolder">Projects</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1  top-puller bolder">Blog</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1  top-puller bolder">Contact</div>

    </div>
```

```
.top-puller{
  margin-top: 20px;
 }
 .bolder{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: because projects text is quite long. it seems to go beyond the parent container. Increase the width of the div to accommodate the text

Comment: Because `col-md-1` is 8.333333% width of it's container. The columns don't change size based on their content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the header structure:

CSS:

```
.top-puller {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.bolder li {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-default top-puller">
        <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right bolder">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx,but how to add here navbar-brand?